# How to select only one row that satisfies one of multiple ordered conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have customers that have multiple addresses. Each customer/address combination has its own line in the database (Oracle) table.

I am trying to achieve a query in which, if the customer has a 'Main Address', I display only the Main Address, 
otherwise if he has a Shipment Address, I display only the Shipment Address, 
otherwise if he has a 'Secondary Address', I display the Secondary Address, 
otherwise I display nothing.

This order is important, and the problem is that the entries in the database are in no specific order, meaning that the same customer might be found to have a Shipment Address first, and a Main Address later on. Therefore I don't simply need the first row that satisfies one of the conditions...

I tried this, but it returns a result for each line, e.g. multiple results for one person:

```
CASE WHEN ADR = 'MAIN' THEN 'MAIN'
         WHEN ADR = 'SHIPMENT' THEN 'SHIPMENT' 
         WHEN ADR = 'SECONDARY' THEN 'SECONDARY' 
         ELSE null
    END AS Adressart
```

To clarify, the input looks as follows:

```
CUSTOMER_NR ADDRESS_TYPE
1           SHIPMENT
1           MAIN
2           SHIPMENT
3           SECONDARY
3           SHIPMENT
4           SECONDARY
```

The results would look like this:

```
CUSTOMER_NR ADDRESS_TYPE
1           MAIN
2           SHIPMENT
3           SHIPMENT
4           SECONDARY
```

Comment: Are you using mysql or oracle?

Comment: I'm using Oracle (see tags. I've also edited the post.)

Comment: Please don't tag oracle questions with the MySQL tag, please. Thank you.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/ -- Is this relevant?

Comment: Not exactly. I don't need a row that meets any one of the conditions, I need a row that meets a condition in that specific order.

Comment: So partitioning on the customer and ordering by the expression you have won't work? I think I missunderstand the question in that case, could you show me some sample input and output?

Comment: Please see the edited post. I added an example

Comment: Does your table have a primary key? If so this will work(replace ID with your ID, and mytable with your table name): `SELECT CUSTOMER_NR , ADDRESS_TYPE FROM ( SELECT First_Value(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_NR ORDER BY CASE WHEN ADDRESS_TYPE = 'MAIN' THEN 1 WHEN ADDRESS_TYPE = 'SECONDARY' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END ASC) First, ID, CUSTOMER_NR, ADDRESS_TYPE FROM mytable ) WHERE ID = First;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use multiple joins to the address table and by using `coalesce` return only the one address from the order

The query would look something like:

```
SELECT      customer_nr, coalesce(a1.address, a2.address, a3,address) AS address
FROM        customer AS c 
LEFT JOIN   address AS a1 where a1.customer_nr = c.customer_nr and a1.address_type = 'MAIN'
LEFT JOIN   address AS a2 where a2.customer_nr = c.customer_nr and a2.address_type = 'SHIPMENT'
LEFT JOIN   address AS a3 where a3.customer_nr = c.customer_nr and a3.address_type = 'SECONDARY'
```

Comment: a3.address... not a3,address

Answer (score 0):

The following query would get you the desired result:

```
SELECT
  CUSTOMER_NR,
  ADDRESS_TYPE
FROM
(
  select 
  customer_nr,
  address_type,
  row_number () over (partition by customer_nr order by 
                      case address_type
                        when 'MAIN' then 1
                        when 'SHIPMENT' then 2
                        when 'SECONDARY' THEN 3
                        else 4
                      end) rn
from addresses
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

First, the addresses are sorted using the priority with a CASE statement. Then, only the address types that have rn = 1 (the address type of highest priority) are selected.

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b88f6/3)</kbd>